# How can i access in host file whiles using a proxy server

Tags: proxy, iis

I using a proxy server (Freegate to be specific). I an unable to access the connections (dns mappings) that i have set in my host file.

That is i want to access "127.0.0.1 YourInstanceName" whiles using the proxy server. Its not fun always having to turn of the proxy server before i can work. Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox, you can goto proxy settings and in text box at the bottom, enter the hosts that you do not want proxied.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage the proxy server, you could create static DNS A records for the domains that you need to access.  If you control the PAC file (given you use a proxy.pac file to connect to your proxy), you can create exceptions in the file for the domains you are trying to connect to.  Are the hostnames you have in your HOSTS file actual real-world resolvable domains that you want to redirect to a new IP address?

Comment: Its a local site (IIS Server), and I am using freegate software.